# What does: malloc(10) and malloc(10*sizeof(int))

Tags: malloc

Does `malloc(10)` allocate 10 bytes of memory?
And `malloc(10 * sizeof(int))` allocate 40 bytes of memory ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as the memory usable by your code, and assuming that `sizeof(int)` on your target system is 4, both answers are "yes". However, two additional considerations apply:

- `malloc` uses a small amount of memory to account for the blocks that it allocates to  your program, resulting in some implementation-dependent overhead
- internally `malloc` could allocate more memory than your code has requested. Although the additional memory is not usable by your code, it becomes unavailable for further allocations.

This becomes important when you call `malloc` multiple times: for example, when you call `malloc(10)` 1,000,000 times, the amount of usable memory may go down by several additional megabytes, compared to the expected 10MB + `malloc`'s overhead.